# User Self Registration - Missing user details after registration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I´m trying to use "User Self Registration" but without success. The users are getting created and email received, but the users details are missing.

I configured 3 claims for user registration - firstName, LastName and email.
I have selected this 3 claims as "Supported by Default : true", " Required : true" and mapped Attributes to the desired userstore.

I am filling firstName, LastName, email and password in the registration form, but after user creation not all the user details are saved in the database. Even if I register users in the primary userStore the problem remains.
I´m able to see user creation details in the database, but not all the desired details.. Email is present but firstName and LastName are missing.

What I´m missing here ? Could you help me with this issue ?

WSO2 IS 5.10.0

Thank you for your time!

Best regards,
Frank

Comment: Can you check if the claims are configured correctly? if they are not saving that means the mapped attributes are not there in the user store you configured.

Comment: Did you check whether if you update a user profile from management console, whether the values are persisted without an issue?